# Translucent png become black opaque or even brown opaque in app?

Tags: ios, png, translucency

Here, I have a png for customing the appearance of my table or something, of course in the **IOS**.

and after our designer, who draws these pictures, completed a png, and part of it is translucent which is designed for a shadow effect, and she says that she just change the alpha value of that part to make it translucent.

And the results is, when I put this png into the app, all the places of the png that are supposed to be translucent and leave a shadow, turn out to become totally opaque, black or brown, some strange dark color.

Hoping anyone could help me to solve this!

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Screen shots would help and posting a sample of the PNG. Flag to re-open when done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alpha transparency values relate to how much it is blended with the background.  An alpha value of 50%, for example, will show 50% of the background color, and 50% of the foreground color.  It's very likely that the color results you are seeing are because the background onto which you are placing the image is colored in some particular way.  Try adjusting this appropriately.

Alternatively, the platform you are using doesn't support transparent PNGs, but you've not told us anything about that, so I can only speculate.

Comment: Sorry, I am developing on IOS, and I have been puzzled by this for a relatively long time, do you develope IOS app too?